# AWS Lambda triggered multiple times while uploading one s3 bucket file python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to trigger a lambda event when a png image file is uploaded to a specific s3 bucket. Everything working fine in my lambda function and it is triggering the event while uploading the file. The problem is, it is triggering the lambda function multiple times.

The Lambda function is working, and whenever upload a file to an S3 bucket-designated folder or a sub-folder it resizes .png images to 50% in width and height.
But we have one issue to replace the file in the same location with the same extension. Lambda trigger works when the file is inserted into the S3 so when we upload a new file S3 triggers the lambda and then lambda increases the size by 50% and replaced the file in the bucket but when the file is replaced lambda triggered another event. So that is the issue.

For example-  We have uploaded 1 MB .pnj with 1000X500, and it is resizing it to 1500X750 but the file storage size is continuously increasing by 1MB - 1.7MB -2.4MB -3.1MB -4.6MB continue and the dimension is also increasing. Once it tries to continue this process it throws a runtime error since out of memory.

I need to solve this using two ways. Either way will work fine. First I need to stop the lambda trigger happen for only once then it will solve my issue. or Another way is that we need to change our lambda function as such if one uploaded image is already processed or resized then we won't resize it again for that I need some indicator that will tell me that this image is already resized. How to find that indicator? [Note: when the first trigger happens the image will get the resized with required height and width so if we can any condition in the second call and return nothing then maybe it would work but what condition do I need to put here]

Comment: you could filter s3 notification using path. upload file in a folder and let the lambda write the output file into another folder.

Comment: But what if I want the same file to be resized like replace the image with new image in the same folder

Comment: The simple solution would be to write them to another prefix and do what @brushtakopo suggests. The only other alternative is that you somehow (e.g.) in a database like DynamoDB keep track of objects you've already processed and check there before (re-)processing an item.

Comment: There are multiple possibilities.  One such possibility:  Add a custom tag on the image with `Metadata={"seen": "yes"}`, then skip files that have the `["Metadata"]["seen"]` value set when you call get_object.

Comment: @sohanur shanto Look at [put_object boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object), you can send a dictionary to `put_object` with argument name `Metadata`. Although it might be better to maintain a separate prefix for unprocessed objects, that way your lambda won't get triggered needlessly for processed objects and increase costs.

Comment: Great got it. Worked fine now. Added metadata and when it is getting called second time it will return nothing if metadata seen is yes.